# Newtonsoft Json - Different Null Handling values for Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-5

I want to enable the `null` request values while my API deserializes http request body but I do not want my api to ignore `null` values while sending the response. I.e.:

- Ignore null values when deserializing
- Do not ignore null values when serializing

How can I achieve this globally?

This was not an issue on .Net Framework 4.7.2, and our front-end was designed to meet above criteria. Now it's creating this huge problem while we convert our api to .NET 5.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
             {
                 options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include; // This enables null values for both serialization/deserialization which does not suit my needs.
     
                 (options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver).NamingStrategy = null;
             })
             .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
             {
                 // Create output in PascalCase instead of camelCase
                 jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                 jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
                 jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition =          System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.Never;
             })
}
```

Comment: I've noticed `nullable` was internally enabled in JSON.Net going from 12.0.3 to 13.0.0, might that be the issue here? Have you upgraded JSON.Net version?

Comment: And what looks weird is that you are calling `AddNewtonsoftJson`, which enabled JSON.Net, while in the next part you are setting the options for `System.Text.Json`. These are two competing JSON frameworks. Not a good idea to combine them. (I advise to stop using JSON.Net... since 13 it's been giving headaches. Microsoft's System.Text.Json is good enough for most situations)

Comment: Does `System.Text.Json` have the feature I mentioned above? It only has `DefaultIgnoreCondition` which I can set which is then taken into considiration while `serializing`. But couldn't find anything for `deserializing`

Comment: *This was not an issue on .Net Framework 4.7.2, and our front-end was designed to meet above criteria.* - might you please share what you did in 4.7.2 that worked as required?

Comment: I didn't do anything and `Newtonsoft` package handled the situation as mentioned above. It doesn't care if `null` comes in the request, it automatically sets the `default` to that property. But when serializing, it serializes all properties without checking for `null` values. @dbc

Comment: And it's not doing that any more?  Can you reproduce standalone?  I don't see anything in the [13 release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/13.0.1) that could account for the change.  Agree with @JHBonarius that calling both `AddNewtonsoftJson()` and `AddJsonOptions()` looks risky, are you sure that the second call didn't cancel out the first and enable System.Text.Json instead?

Comment: It does a lot. But you'll have to check the docs. e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: And actually, might you please clarify what you mean by *I want to enable the null request values while my API deserializes http request body but I do not want my api to ignore null values while sending the response.*  You mean that you want `null` values to be ignored when deserialized?  When serialized?  Both?  Neither?  A [mcve] showing how you achieved your needs in .Net Framework 4.7.2 might help clarify.

Comment: p.s. _"while we convert our api to .NET 5."_... that must be a slow progress... .Net 7 will be released any moment now. Might as well skip 5 and 6 as they will go out of support soon...

Comment: @dbc What I want is, `Do not ignore null values when serializing` and `Ignore null values when deserializing`.  @JHBonarius it's kind of a license problem at the moment. We don't have the license for Visual Studio 2022 hence cannot move forward with .NET 6 ot 7.

Comment: While I provided a "pure" Json.NET solution in my answer, I'd still like to know how you did this in .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a "pure" Json.NET setting that

- Skips `null` values when deserializing.
- Emits `null` values when serializing.

Then I am unaware of any built-in serializer setting for this specifically.  Instead what you could do is add a root-level converter that sets `serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` when deserializing, and does nothing when serializing:

```
public class IgnoreNullValuesWhenDeserializingRootConverter : JsonConverter
{
    // Disables the converter in a thread-safe manner to prevent a stack overflow as the converter calls itself.
    [ThreadStatic]
    static bool disabled;
    bool Disabled { get { return disabled; } set { disabled = value; } }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override bool CanRead => !Disabled;
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => !Disabled;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) 
    {
        using (new PushValue<bool>(true, () => Disabled, val => Disabled = val))
        using (new PushValue<NullValueHandling>(NullValueHandling.Ignore, () => serializer.NullValueHandling, val => serializer.NullValueHandling = val))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public struct PushValue<T> : IDisposable
{
    Action<T> setValue;
    T oldValue;

    public PushValue(T value, Func<T> getValue, Action<T> setValue)
    {
        if (getValue == null || setValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.oldValue = getValue();
        setValue(value);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    // By using a disposable struct we avoid the overhead of allocating and freeing an instance of a finalizable class.
    public void Dispose() => setValue?.Invoke(oldValue);

    #endregion
}
```

Then initialize `options` as follows:

```
options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IgnoreNullValuesWhenDeserializingRootConverter()); //Ignore null values when deserializing
options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include; // Do not ignore null values when serializing
```

Notes:

- This will not work if your root model also has its own custom `JsonConverter` applied.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X3FBI9).

Comment: This seems to do the job right now.  Also, I didn't add `any` configuration on the .Net Framework 4.7.2 to make this feature work. It just does, out of the case. Json.Net version is `13.0.0` on that project. Thanks!